# How can I add a special classes to all block of custom kind?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

Is there any `hook_preprocess_block` or any other way to I can add my custom classes to all blocks of a custom kind?Or in the other words:
How can I target all blocks of custom kind?

For example I want to add `search` class to all search blocks (or target all search blocks in my theme by using default auto-generated classes by Drupal core if it be available), or add `user-login` class to all user login blocks and so forth in my theme without any need to create a template for every block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no problem to add classes in a block preprocess hook:

```
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;

  function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = Html::getClass('block-id-' . $variables['elements']['#id']);
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = Html::getClass('block-plugin-' . $variables['elements']['#base_plugin_id']);
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = Html::getClass('block-provider-' . $variables['elements']['#configuration']['provider']);
  }
```

This example simply adds the available information to all blocks. You can start with this and narrow it down to what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and attention, I appreciate you very much,This answer is great solution 
for common blocks targeting in pervasive status,
But this method also have a little problem and it seems that it not be very useful for views generated blocks like:
`Recent content` because all blocks of this kind have unique numeric Id like:
`block-views-block-content-recent-block-1-2`
and I can't target all of those blocks effective.
Anyway, I thank you very much.

Comment: In `#derivative_plugin_id` you'll find `[view name]-[display id]`, the last part of the block id.